# Unable to test a lodash debounced vue method

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, lodash, vue-test-utils

I've been trying to test a confirmation button using jest and vue-test-utils. I'm using a debounced method to handle accidental double-clicking.

I've tried using jest.useFakeTimers() and jest.runOnlyPendingTimers(), but I'm still not seeing my button text changing in my tests. I've created an isolated test file below - any advice on what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated!

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import _ from 'lodash'

jest.useFakeTimers()

const myComponent = {

    data(){

        return {
            confirming: false
        }

    },

    computed: {

        state(){

            return this.confirming ? 'are you sure?' : 'default'

        }

    },

    template: `<div @click="changeState">{{ state }}</div>`,

    methods: {

        changeState(){

            this.doConfirm()

        },

        doConfirm: _.debounce(function(){

            if(!this.confirming){
                this.confirming = true
            }else{
                this.confirming = false
            }

        }, 500)

    }

}

describe('Testing debounce methods', () => {

    let $wrapper

    beforeEach(() => {

        $wrapper = shallowMount(myComponent)

    })

    test('Check default state', () => {

        expect($wrapper.text()).toContain('default')

    })

    test('Check state changes with click', () => {

        $wrapper.trigger('click')

        jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()

        expect($wrapper.text()).toContain('are you sure?')

    })

})
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `this` is unbound inside the `debounce(function()`; try logging `this`, maybe use an arrow fn `_.debounce(() => { if... })`

Comment: I actually get `this` as `undefined` when I used `() => {` and the component method no longer works

Comment: Kindly let me know if you found a fix for this ?